# Como fazer com que layout não seja empurrado para cima quando o teclado do meu app aparece?

Tags: android-layout, layout

Layout da minha aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O bug acontece quando clico em qualquer um dos editTexts para adicionar um valor qualquer aos mesmos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, o anúncio e dois dos balõezinhos sobem. No caso, até que **o anúncio subir não me é um problema e pode ser mantido**.

A solução que procuro para o meu problema é como fazer para os dois balõezinhos não subirem assim que o usuário abra o teclado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução que encontrei resolveu o problema do layout se distorcendo, mas com isso o anúncio permaneceu embaixo, o que achei preferível em relação ao estado anterior.

Para isso adicionei a `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` às activitys no AndroidManifest.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]